# как правильно сделать шаблонизацию ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, шаблоны, ejs

```js
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        Photo.find({}, function (error, photos) {
            var photoList = '';

            photos.forEach(function (photo) {
                photoList += '\
                    <a href="/sight-photo" style="background-image: url(' + photo.filePhoto + ')" class="photo_gallery-wrapper">\
                        <span class="photo_gallery-title">' + photo.titlePhoto + '</span>\
                        <span class="photo_gallery-desc-hover">\


                        </span>\
                    </a>\
                ';
            });

            res.render('index.ejs', {photoList: photoList});
        });
    });

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<% if (photoList.length) {
 <% for(var i=0; i < photoList.length; i++) { %>
   <a href="/sight-photo" style="background-image: url(<%=photo.filePhoto%>" class="photo_gallery-wrapper">
    <span class="photo_gallery-title"><%=photo.titlePhoto%></span>
 </a>
 <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Жестоко, конечно.

Answer (score 2):

Контроллер:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Photo.find({}, function (error, photos) {
        res.render('index.ejs', { photos: photos });
    });
});
```

Шаблон, `index.ejs`:

```
<% photos.forEach(function(photo) { %>
    <a href="/sight-photo" style="background-image: url(<%=photo.filePhoto%>" class="photo_gallery-wrapper">
        <span class="photo_gallery-title">
            <%=photo.titlePhoto%>
        </span>
    </a>
<% } %>
```

Comment: по-другому сделала. спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @vita_run там напишите сами ответ, чтобы другим тоже помогло.

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере не должно быть html. В шаблон передавайте `photo` и там цикл прогоняйте:

```
<% if (photoList.length) {
    <% for(var i=0; i < photoList.length; i++) { %>
       <!-- Здесь html -->
    <% } %>  


<% } %>
```

Comment: до этого использовала hjs. думала, тут так же прокатит. Подправила шаблон. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тогда в контроллере останется?

Comment: @vita_run весь код по работе с html убрать из контроллера в шаблон. А шаблон передавать массив фоток и там уже в цикле формировать html.